# vue 2 v-if, computed, firebase

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a component in a tab :

```
<md-tabs>
    <md-tab v-for="event in events" :key="event.uid" :md-label="event.title">
        <subscribe :eventKey="event['.key']"></subscribe>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

I would like this component to be display just if my condition is true (so i think a v-if is ok)
I try to put the v-if in my subscribe component like this :

```
<template v-if="sub">
    ...
</template>
```

with a computed like this :

```
computed: {
    sub: function () {
        let currentUser = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser
        let path = 'events/' + this._props.eventKey + '/subscriber'
        firebaseDB.ref(path).once('value', snapshot => {
            console.log(_.some(snapshot.val(), {'id': currentUser.uid}))
            return _.some(snapshot.val(), {'id': currentUser.uid})
        })
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work :(
My console.log in return me some true and some false from my firebase database but the component still here.

I try inside the template, with a methods, i try in the parents but it is never work.

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: the `sub` computed function never returns anything

Comment: There is a return in this function. I don't understand why you say it's never return anything. What is wrong here so ?

Comment: There is a `return` in the callback function passed to `firebaseDB.ref(path).once`. The `sub` computed function itself does not have a `return`, so that property will always be `undefined`